# Why do I get the account id as the user id in Laravel's Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a multi-tenant site where each account has their own set of users... In my Users controller, I have an `update` method that fetches the user with the following:

```
    $user = User::whereUsername($username)
        ->leftJoin('accounts', 'accounts.id', '=', 'users.account_id')
        ->where('accounts.id', '=', DB::raw('users.account_id'))
        ->where('accounts.subdomain', '=', $subdomain)
        ->firstOrFail();
```

Problem is, when I do `$user->id`, it's giving me the `accounts.id` instead...

I was able to fix this by adding `->select('users.id as id')` but I'd like to know why it happen and if there is a better way to avoid it. I would think that since I'm selecting from `users` that the columns in the `users` table would take priority in any naming conflicts...

Comment: Probably what you want is to select `users.*` and nothing from `accounts` table, because you only need to apply that `WHERE` clause there, right? Then use `firstOrFail(['users.*'])`, otherwise there is no way for `Eloquent` to guess which `id` you'd like. Also I suppose you need `join` instead of `leftJoin`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for Laravel to know which id should take priority. Normally, if you would try to select it in SQL, you would get an error saying id is ambigeous. You can just select it in SQL by using its table name. To avoid confusion in Laravel, you could use aliases in your select statement. You did that, which is good. Try moving database related tasks out of your controller.